# How to format time string in VB.NET to AM/PM?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to format a date string. My function currently generates "16:00". I want it to generate "4:00 PM". Here is my code:

```
Dim eventTime As String
eventTime = Trim(odbcReader("StartTime").ToString)
```

I tried this:

```
eventTime = Trim(odbcReader("StartTime").ToString("hh:mm tt"))
```

But it returns nothing. How do I get the date string to format properly?

Comment: What is the value of that column? I suspect it is just an `object` that doesn't know about format strings. First cast to DateTime, *then* call ToString with that format string

Answer (score 1):

You can't format a `String` as a `String`. If you want to format a time then you have to start with a time, i.e. a `TimeSpan` value or a `DateTime` value. You need to convert your existing `String` to one of those types, then convert that to a `String` in the desired format.

As you want a time of day, you need to create a `DateTime`. A `TimeSpan` just represents a period of time without reference to a start or end point, so it can't be directly formatted the way you want. You would need something like this:

```vb
Dim s1 = "16:00"
Dim t = DateTime.Parse(s1)
Dim s2 = t.ToString("h:mm tt")
```

Note that the format specifier is "h:mm tt", "hh:mm tt". You specifically said that you expect a result without a leading zero so you wouldn't provide a format specifier that would create a leading zero.

Comment: @PageCOW, why are you asking me something that you can test for yourself? Do you think that my time is less valuable than yours?